# Extracting text inbetween HTML tags

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this string:

```
In December 2011, Norway's largest online sex shop hemmelig.com was <a href="http://www.dazzlepod.com/hemmelig/?page=93" target="_blank" rel="noopener">hacked by a collective calling themselves &quot;Team Appunity&quot;</a>. The attack exposed over 28,000 usernames and email addresses along with nicknames, gender, year of birth and unsalted MD5 password hashes.
```

*(don't ask)*

Inside of that string sits an HREF link to the site itself, what I need to do is extract the information between the tags `<a href=""></a>`. So the end result should look like this:

```
In December 2011, Norway's largest online sex shop hemmelig.com was hacked by a collective calling themselves &quot;Team Appunity&quot;. The attack exposed over 28,000 usernames and email addresses along with nicknames, gender, year of birth and unsalted MD5 password hashes.
```

What I've been able to do so far is match the whole tag using a regular expression and replacing it with nothing:

```
def get_unlinked_description(descrip):
    html_tag_regex = re.compile(r"<.+>", re.I)
    return html_tag_regex.sub("", descrip)
```

However the output of this, as you would expect, removes the whole string:

```
In December 2011, Norway's largest online sex shop hemmelig.com was . The attack exposed over 28,000 usernames and email addresses along with nicknames, gender, year of birth and unsalted MD5 password hashes
```

How can I successfully extract the information between the tags, along with removing the tags, without removing the full string?
.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

As far as your implementation. The code used would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

soup.href.string
```

Where `html_doc` would be the string or the document you wish to parse and `'html.parser'` is the python command you wish to run.

This should finally return `In December 2011, Norway's largest online sex shop hemmelig.com was hacked by a collective calling themselves &quot;Team Appunity&quot;. The attack exposed over 28,000 usernames and email addresses along with nicknames, gender, year of birth and unsalted MD5 password hashes.`